# ¿Cómo etiquetar datapoints de clusters con clusplot?

Tags: r, cluster

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente *dataset*, que almacena información sobre diferentes países:

```
    ctr        country  i1  i2  i3  i4  i5  i6 cluster
1   AFE    Africa East  64  27  41  52  32  40       3
2   AFW    Africa West  77  20  46  54   9  78       1
6   ARA      Arab_ctrs  80  38  53  68  23  34       3
7   ARG      Argentina  49  46  56  86  20  62       1
9   AUL      Australia  38  90  61  51  21  71       5
10  AUT        Austria  11  55  79  70  60  63       4
...
```

Mi objetivo es aplicar *k-means* para diferenciar los diferentes clusters (países similares). El código es el siguiente:

```
full_data <- read.csv("indexes.csv", sep = ";") 
data <- na.omit(full_data)

set.seed(20)
clusters <- kmeans(data[,3:8], centers = 5, nstart=25)

data$cluster <- as.factor(clusters$cluster)

library(cluster)
clusplot(data, data$cluster, main="Countries-by-index", 
         color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=2, lines=0)
```

El gráfico que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: Clusters del dataset]

Como se puede ver, junto a cada uno de los puntos aparece un número. Me gustaría saber qué significa y cómo puedo sustituirlo por una etiqueta que identifique el país correspondiente (la columna `ctr` del *dataset*).

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación de [`custplot()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cluster/versions/2.1.0/topics/clusplot)

> **The labels of the points are the rownames of x if x is matrix like**.
>   Otherwise (diss = TRUE), x is a vector, point labels can be attached
>   to x as a "Labels" attribute (attr(x,"Labels")), as is done for the
>   output of daisy.

por lo que una forma en que puedes establecer las etiquetas para cada punto, es nombrando cada fila de tu `data.frame` mediante:

```
rownames(data ) <- data$ctr
```

Recuerda que el `rowname` debe ser único.

PD: El numero que aparece actualmente es el `rowname` actual

Comment: Solucionado. ¡Muchas gracias!